# Permission Denied (publickey)/fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly?

Tags: git, github, ssh

So I started the production for a Jekyll site using the following commands,

```
$ git clone https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap.git USERNAME.github.com
$ cd USERNAME.github.com
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.github.com.git
```

After getting a local and github repo set up, I tried to send the changes to github,

```
$ git push origin master
```

to find this,

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What did I do wrong? What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permission denied (publickey) means that that the server rejected your connection. Check https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey for details

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you haven't initialized SSH keys with Github. This solved it for me:

```
cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen
cat id_rsa.pub
```

and copy the key into the SSH settings of the Github website.

Then you're good to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You create SSH From Github Account.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: just for the records: how to do it with Bitbucket https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/How+to+install+a+public+key+on+your+Bitbucket+account

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing large files then try this, It will change the pushing capacity to 500 MB

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

or try this, set the origin to master

```
$ git push origin master
```

or Check your proxy setting of internet connection.If you are using some proxy then change it to noproxy. git push will work in noproxy mode.