# Git Push from Xcode and Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, git, package, push

I build a project based on Perfect Framework so I use Swift Package Manager and have dependencies from framework libs. My problem is that when swift builds an app it executes git clone for every dependency, so when I try to commit my changes and push them to remote XCode collects all git repositories from the project. As a result, I have eight remote repositories checked and I have to uncheck them every time. I don't want to push anything to dependency-related repositories, I want to push only my project.

This is my Package.swift:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "LPServer",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(
            url: "git://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git",
            majorVersion: 2, minor: 0
        )
    ]
)
```

This is what I see when I try to make Push:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVxHD.png)

The only workaround that I see now is to push from Terminal. The problem should be very common for those who uses SPM so I'm sure that solution is there. Please help me to find it.

Comment: I think the problem appeared because you forked or cloned a complete git project instead of crating own clean git project and adding dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the url:

```
url: "git@github.com:PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git"
```

Comment: In this case I get the following error:

**$ swift package fetch**
Cloning git@github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git
/usr/bin/git clone --recursive --depth 10 git@github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git /Users/***/LPServer/Packages/Perfect-HTTPServer.git
**fatal:** repository 'git@github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git' does not exist

**error:** Failed to clone git@github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git to /Users/***/LPServer/Packages/Perfect-HTTPServer.git

Comment: Yes, semicolon makes more sense, however there is another error now:

`Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

error: Failed to clone git@github.com:PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git to /Users/***`

Comment: Can you clone the repository in terminal?

Comment: If you do have a permissions for this repository, you need to configure your account in Github by adding you public ssh key there. If you don't have public ssh key file (usually ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) you can create it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21052680/637589